# Text pasted in CKEditor isn't clean

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

On a Drupal 8 installation, with CKEditor enabled for Full HTML format, when I paste text from Word with cmd+V, the source code includes format that makes the code dirty.

Example:

```
<p><span style="font-size:12pt"><span style="line-height:115%"><span style="font-family:Helvetica">Lorem ipsum dolor.</span></span></span></p>
```

How can I force it to clean the code from Word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

- there is a special "Paste from Word"-button in CKeditor, add it to your toolbar
- limit allowed HTML tags, it will strip unwanted tags attributes when saving the node (by default `span`s are allowed, but `style` attributes will be removed by default)

Both can be done in `Configuration > Content authoring > Text formats and editors`

Comment: "limit allowed HTML tags" worked for me, thanks @Hudri. "Paste from Word"-button dowsn't work in some browsers, for example in Chrome for Mac shows the error: "Your browser doesn't allow you to paste this way. Press ⌘+V to paste."

Comment: Yes, I do get the same message when pasting in chrome for windows, but it did work in IE

Answer (score 2):

For reference, there was a backwards-compatibility break in CKEditor v4.6 - it removed some of its own paste-from-Word button's cleaning. See this discussion on the Drupal side: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2871539

Note [comment #6](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2871539#comment-12233251) there offers another workaround - responding to the 
`afterPasteFromWord` CKEditor event in some custom Javascript and filtering exactly as desired.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is only for **CKEditor in Drupal**.
I can recommend two modules to clean up pasted text (not only from Word) into the CKEditor:

[CKEditor Paste Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_paste_filter).
This module **works out of the box** without further settings.

[Paste Format (filter, clean-up pasted text)](https://www.drupal.org/project/pasteformat/issues/2920249).
This module has **no stable release** (Feb 2022) for Drupal 8/9, but the linked port to Drupal 8/9 works quite well. Nevertheless, **I prefer it** to the first module, because it works by using a "normal" textformat like "Plain Text". Because of that you have the opportunity **to further tweek and restrict the pasted text**.
I am using a custom textformat "Pasteformat" with "Convert line breaks into HTML" and "Limit allowed HTML tags and correct faulty HTML" enabled for the following tags:

```
<a href title> <i> <b> <em> <strong> <cite> <blockquote cite> <code> <ul type> <ol start type='1 A I'> <li> <dl> <dt> <dd> <h2> <h3> <h4> <h5> <h6><br><p> <table> <th> <tr> <td> <thead> <tbody> <tfoot>
```

For "Paste Format" i also recommend the installation of the following modules and enabling them in your textformat for pasting text:

[No Non-breaking Space Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/no_nbsp) to **remove &nbsp;** (has to be the first filter in the textformat).

[Filter Empty Tags](https://www.drupal.org/project/filter_empty_tags) to **remove empty tags** and lines (last filter in the textformat).

After all i can safely give the website to customers which want to paste text from word into the editor – without the risk of breaking design and typography.  ;-)